# Formik : Validation by field

Tags: reactjs, formik

Formik call validation for ALL fields on validation.
Changes in some field, leads to validation execution for all others fields in the form. It happens when i am using independent field validation by passing a validate prop to a component.

I am using field validation by passing a validate prop to a component like below:

```
<Field 
    type="text" 
    name={field.name}  
    placeholder={field.caption}
    options={field.options || undefined}
    label={field.caption}
    component={stringToComponentMapper[field.component]}
    type={field.component}
    validate={this.isRequired}
/>
```

```
       isRequired = value => {
        console.log(value);
       }
         <Form>
                <FieldArray
                    name='fields'
                    render = { arrayHelpers => (
                      <div>
                        {formFields.fields && formFields.fields.length > 0 &&
                         formFields.fields.map((field, index) => (
                            <div key={field.name}>
                              <Field 
                                type="text" 
                                name={field.name}  
                                placeholder={field.caption}
                                options={field.options || undefined}
                                label={field.caption}
                                component={stringToComponentMapper[field.component]}
                                type={field.component}
                                validate={this.isRequired}
                              /> 
                              <ErrorMessage name={field.name}/>
                            </div>
                         ))
                        }
                        <button type='submit' className='btn'>Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    )}
                />
              </Form>
```

For example: while typing on email field,the validation invokes for all fields.

Comment: Would you mind creating a working example using a service like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: @Rallen
Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/x7j9499yrp

Try to edit 'First Name' field and see the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per field validation in `Formik` does not mean a field is validated if necessary. It means that each field can get custom validation that suits the users needs (e.g. custom email validation, etc.). So to check for requirement inside the field your `isRequired` function has to be changed as follows:

```
const isRequired = (value) => {
    return !value ? "Required" : "";
}
```

`Formik` does not validate each field seperately as it is changed, but instead runs validation on every field if something changed. **This behaviour is at the time of this answer intended by the creator of the library**.

Comment: Agree, but my question is that, when I am modifying the data in "First Name" field then why the **isRequired** method is getting invoked for rest of the fields? It should only invoke for "First Name" field only.

Comment: As I said, per field validation does not mean per field as in validate `firstName` if edited, it means custom validation procedures, e.g. you want `firstName` never to be `Aaron` (sorry to all Aarons)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get this line.
**you want firstName never to be Aaron**.
Can you explain ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
But i have one more doubt. As you said, validate will invoke for the rest of the field as well. So let say, if there is a site which has more form fields then will it impact the performance?

Comment: If you ever have performance issues with `Formik`, use the `FastField` component instead of `Field` component. But that is not part of the question you asked.

Comment: @Tushky Don´t forget to mark this answer as the accepted answer if it helped solving your problem.

Comment: An open issue was posted on the repo suggesting alternatives to this design decision [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/512). Sadly, it has not been resolved but a possible workaround for this post might be offered [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/512#issuecomment-473040060) with an amendment [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/512#issuecomment-519156956).